# Secure MySQL 8 installation on Ubuntu 20.04 Problem

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I`m trying to install and configure mysql and phpmyadmin, but after installation mysql-server, when I try to use  command mysql_secure_installation terminal ask me to input root password. After  entering, it shows ERROR:

`Securing the MySQL server deployment.
Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I tried install mysql with info from this page https://kifarunix.com/install-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Edit:
https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/what-to-do-if-mysql-sock-file-is-missing/ That didn`t help